# will google analytics work with multiple sharepoint zones?

Tags: sharepoint, google-analytics, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 site that has both Internet and Intranet zones. I want to capture internal and external traffic to the site.
Internet access uses forms based authentication and Intranet access uses windows authentication.

1. Internet: http://www.thesite.org
2. Intranet: http://thesite

Apart from the landing pages, both sites are the same. [Google Analytics Support](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009688?hl=en) suggests that the Intranet must be accessible by a fqdn. But I guess that doesn't apply in this case.

So if I place a google analytics tracking code in my master page would it capture the traffic from both sources? Or do I need a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably not work by default - IIRC cookies can only be set on a fully qualified domain name, and since GA uses cookies it will not work on http://thesite.

A possible workaround might be to disable cookies in GA by setting `storage:none`  when you create the tracker; in that case you have to supply and maintain your own clientid, [e.g](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#disabling_cookies).

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
  'storage': 'none',
  'clientId': '76c24efd-ec42-492a-92df-c62cfd4540a3'
});
```

Comment: Thanks - what if we changed it to a fqdn. Do you know would there be any obstacles then?

Comment: If GA can set cookies and access the internet it will work (but if your domains are different sessions will be restarted when a user changes the domain unless you implement cross domain tracking).